# how to set text exactly bottom of image and also image and bottom text is align perfectly

Tags: html, css, background-image, text-align

hello please read carefully this question this is not duplicate question i want to write text below the background image and and also background image contain background-size:center center; property so when i'm trying to put text below it. the background image and text contents must be in center. please refer my image then you will get what i'm actually trying. the link is posted in the comment box. and also i have provided my code what i have actually already tried. i'm new in cascading style sheets so please help me Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: PLEASE refer this image https://ibb.co/cBbnwF what i'm actually trying to make and this is my code what i have tried https://jsfiddle.net/s1oe4hr9/

Comment: @Rachel Gallen please help me out.

Comment: Just to be clear, your question is how to align text behind the `background-image`, so it's hidden?

Comment: no i just want put text below the image and that image have background-size: center top property. so how to put text below that image?

Comment: Please Help me out Guys i really need help.

Comment: now i'm using background-size:contain property so is it possible to make that happen with this property can someone from stackoverflow professional can answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using an image to be the background of the same element that you are writing your content in... you need a structure more like this:

```
<div class = "layer9">
  <h1><center>Outcome</center></h1>
  <div class = "outcome main norep lay"></div> //background image on this
  <div class = "content"> //content is seperate, but a sibling - that goes below
     <p>kjsdadjaljdlsadla</p>
     <p>kjsdadjaljdlsadla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```